# What is the best setup for low frequency AC simulation and recording?

Tags: voltage, current, ac, voltage-measurement

I need to apply an AC signal (current) of frequency, 0.1 Hz to a device and record the resulting change in voltage over time. I've been thinking a for a long time the best way to achieve this. I have tried using:

1. A potentiostat
2. Signal generator with SMU.

All these have failed. I need advice about the best way to proceed with this please. :)

Comment: Hello and welcome -- your question raises two additional questions: why did your attempts fail? Did you verify that the intended signals were actually generated? What response did the system have? What is the system? Please provide these details. It is better to over-share than under-share!

Comment: Thank you. The potentiostat is unable to measure at the frequency range of interest. Regarding the SMU, I'm using the Keysight b2900a and thus far, I've struggled to achieve any recording!